# ¿ Como se hace un bulk insert a Oracle desde .net con lenguaje C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Como se hace un **bulk-insert** desde .net para una base de datos de Oracle.

Comment: Por regla general, no hay una _mejor forma_. Hay formas diferentes. Así como esta la pregunta, debería cerrase pues se basa en opiniones. Igualmente, puedes salvar la pregunta si la reformulas.

Comment: Encontré la siguiente dirección me pueden confirma que es con este método.  http://www.ayobamiadewole.com/Blog/Bulk-Data-Insertion-into-Oracle-Database-in-Csharp

Comment: @AlejandroSoler La solución expuesta en el link no la conosco, no se si funcione y no habia visto antes, puedes hacer una busqueda en google de OracleBulkCopy y veras que hay varios ejemplos, quiza por popularidad podriamos decir que es mejor una que otra, pero para este caso solo conozco el OBC, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes revisar [OracleBulkCopy](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm)

Puedes bajarlo con **nuget** con el siguiente comando

```
Install-Package Oracle.DataAccess.x86
```

Y en codigo seria algo parecido a

```
using (OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(conexion))
{
  bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TABLA;
  bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100000;
  bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 20000;
  bulkCopy.WriteToServer(data);// checar https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm#CHDHHABB para ver que formato es el mas adecuado para usted      
  bulkCopy.Close();
  bulkCopy.Dispose();
  conexion.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: ¿Para los bulk insert se puede usar trigers o no posible ?

Comment: @AlejandroSoler Este escenario no lo conozco, es una muy buena pregunta, te sugiero que abras una nueva pregunta, estoy seguro que alguien del sitio nos podra ayudar, me he quedado intrigado ;)